# Pandas, what is the difference between truth-values and ambiguous-truth-values? ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

In python 3. with the library pandas,
When using the fallowing code

```
    def check_question(df):
       mylambda = lambda x: x if x==x else x
       return df.apply(mylambda)

    print(check_question(df))
```

The console gave the fallowing ValueError:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

After several tries the fallowing code fixed it:

```
   def check_question(df):
       mylambda = lambda x: x if [x==x] else x
       return df.apply(mylambda)

    print(check_question(df))
```

I known, it is something to do with the pandas library: [Stackoverflow: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

I realize that when encapsulation between [], the expression x==x value changes from an ambiguous-thuth-value to a truth-value.
I have a vague idea of what it means, but if someone can enlight me more about it, it will greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Is there a reason you don't use `.apply(lambda x: x)` directly?

Comment: The expression x == x  outputs True, if x = x. I could wrote x > 2 if I wanted to, it will output True if x = 3, but with pandas, it will generate a ValueError with the code  df.apply(lambda x: x if x>2 else x), (if x>2 is not encapsulated with []). It was the point that I was trying to make. The Boolean output of the expression is what I am interested to. Related to the question, the return output of the lambda function is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is not causing a `ValueError` because you are checking the truth value of a Python list (in this case `[x == x]`), which is defined. In contrast, the truth value of a Series is not defined (as you have mentioned).

See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing